# How to convert interfaces from typescript to javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, react-props

I have typescript code that I want to convert to Javascript:

```
interface Props {
  children?: ReactElement | Array<ReactElement>;
}

const Trail: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
```

How do i convert this to something similar in javascript since theres no interfaces?

Comment: Can you explain your use case exactly? TypeScript compiles to JavaScript; if you want to convert TypeScript to JavaScript, just compile it.  This will remove interfaces and any other trace of the static type system.  It that's not what you want, then you should elaborate what you expect to see that's different.

Comment: You just delete the whole `interface` and the type annotation `: React.FC<Props>`.  You can still destructure your props in the same way, but you lose all of the information about their types because that only exists in typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove it:

```
const Trail = ({ children, ...props }) => {
```

Just look at what Typescript generates.